# Reactjs + Python. Connecting frontend to backend and handling post requests

Tags: python, reactjs, database, project

Hi i am pretty much a beginner and so far i dont have much experience dealing with backend. So I need to build this reactjs + python(flask framework?) to-do list app. This project requires me to store the input written in the react into a database(i'm using MySQL). I pretty much have the frontend working fine however my issue right now is with the backend part of this project. I am able to connect python to the mysql database though.

This will be my issues:

1. how do you connect the frontend part to the backend part
2. how do you handle the post request from the form using python to be able to insert the data into the database
3. I do not know what i need to do first

This is my reactjs code where the input form is used:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import useKeypress from './onkeypresshook'

function Addnote(props) {

    const [notetext,setNotetext] = useState('')
    const wordsleft = 200

    const handlechange=(e)=>{
        setNotetext(e.target.value)
    }

    const handlesave=()=>{
        if(notetext.trim().length>0){
            props.handleaddnote(notetext)
            setNotetext("")
        }
        
    }

    useKeypress(handlesave,"Enter")

    return (
        <form method="POST" action='' target='_blank'>
            <div className='eachlist new'>
                <input className="text-area new" placeholder='Type here to add text...' name="notepad" type="text" value={notetext} onChange={handlechange} maxLength ={wordsleft}/>
                <div className='note-footer'>
                    <small>{wordsleft - notetext.length} remaining</small>
                    <button type="submit"  value="submit" className='save-button' onClick={handlesave} >Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    )
}

export default Addnote
```

this is my file tree:

[image]

thank you so much i hope the community can help and guide me

Answer (score 1):

Great that you want start to learn to code!

I'll answer your question as good as possible and then I'll recommend an alternative to your approach.

### What you could do

A simple way to solve your problem would be via REST API (- Google that term and whatever Python framework you're using).

If you expose a REST API endpoint with your Python app, you can send data to it from your React app using `fetch`.

In your react code, you can remove your `handleSend` and `handleSave` functions, and instead attach a `onSubmit` to your `<form />` component like this:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
  const body = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  // Replace XXXX with the port your Python app is running on
  // and your-endpoint with your route URL.
  fetch('http:localhost:XXXX/your-endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    body
  });
}

// ... later in your form
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
```

### My recommended alternative

Instead of starting out with a multi language stack, learn a single language fullstack framework.

I'd recommend Remix. It uses only JavaScript / TypeScript. And it [has a great tutorial here](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes), that teaches you to read and write to a database!

Good luck on your programming journey!

Comment: Thank you so much, it didnt work at first but after a few tweaks on the code and playing around. I got the app up and running